# Are AMP results shown on tablets?

Tags: amp-html

I have tried using several different simulators for different tablet devices and haven't seen any AMP results when I perform a google search. Is there a set breakpoint as to which mobile and tablet devices receive AMP results from google searches? I know the AMP page can technically render on any device, but I'm wondering about the search results google renders.

Answer (score 4):

Only devices with a screen smaller than 7 inches will have AMP search result.

Source: A Google contact I asked several months ago

Comment: I'm glad for this... AMP and bootstrap = headaches. !important is not allowed in AMP.